# SQL Server syntax issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some very basic SQL here:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
  FROM  (SELECT TOP 8 *
        FROM [BP_BasicPolicy ] 
        )
```

For some reason it does not compile and I get the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

What is the correct syntax? I don't understand why I'm getting this error as I thought it was perfectly legitimate SQL Server syntax

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: add an alias name after the final closing bracket?

Comment: `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is a) meaningless, and b) not allowed in a subquery. What are you *attempting* to do?

Comment: Why do you even need the nested tops?  If you only want 1 record why wouldn't `SELECT top 1 * FROM [BP_BasicPolicy] ORDER BY something` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an alias for the subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 1 t.*
FROM (SELECT TOP 8 *
      FROM [BP_BasicPolicy ] 
     ) t
```

EDIT:

I hesitated to add, that using `top` without `order by` doesn't make sense.  You need some ordering.  So, you can do:

```
SELECT TOP 1 t.*
FROM (SELECT TOP 8 *
      FROM [BP_BasicPolicy ] 
      ORDER BY col1 ASC
     ) t
ORDER BY col2 DESC;
```

Actually, you don't need the `order by` at the outermost level, but it is still a good idea.

Without the `order by`, you might as well do:

```
SELECT TOP 1 t.*
FROM [BP_BasicPolicy ] ;
```

This will choose an arbitrary row.  For a specific one, use `order by`.

Comment: It'll still complain about the `TOP` without `ORDER BY` in the subquery.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever on SQL Server? I've never had a problem with it on 2008, 2012, 2014.

Comment: @JChao - I was misremembering which way around the error is reported. It'll definitely complain about `ORDER BY` without `TOP`, but this way around, it is of course just completely non-deterministic.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever -- why would it complain about not using the TOP keyword? Using ORDER BY without TOP is very common. I agree with your conclusion, but that part of your comment confused me.

Comment: @MJB - in the outer query, where `ORDER BY` defines the order of results, sure, but in a subquery, `ORDER BY` is only useful to actually define the meaning of `TOP` (or for generating XML) so `ORDER BY` in a subquery without TOP or FOR XML generates an error.

Comment: Using TOP without ORDER BY is saying that you don't care which row(s), just return some in any order. Here is an excellent article on the topic. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx

Answer (score 0):

your query can be simplified as below, however if your intention isnt like that, please specify the objective, cheer :)

```
SELECT TOP 1 *  FROM [BP_BasicPolicy ]
```

Comment: As many others have already pointed out...TOP with no ORDER BY is non-deterministic.